# Solspace User - Generating a Radio button from a custom member field

Tags: solspace, solspace-user

Solspace's documentation seems to suggest I can generate a radio list from a customer member field if that member field is set to SELECT type.

> This variable pair is a flexible method for creating pull-down menus, radio button arrays, etc. In the variable pair, you precede the short_name of the member field with select_ .[Link to Documenation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/#select_custom_member_field)

However I cannot work out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you would do this:

```
{select_CUSTOM_MEMBER_FIELD}
    <label><input type="radio" name="CUSTOM_MEMBER_FIELD" value="{value}" {selected} /> Custom Member Field Label</label>
{/select_CUSTOM_MEMBER_FIELD}
```

However, since `{selected}` will output `selected="selected"`, when what you actually need is `checked="checked"`, I'm not sure how they figure this can be used for radio inputs. Maybe you can also use a variables named `{checked}` which will populate based on the current value?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Derek's help I was able to work up a solution:

```
{select_CUSTOM_MEMBER_FIELD}
        <label><input type="radio" name="CUSTOM_MEMBER_FIELD" value="{value}" {checked} /> {value}</label>
    {/select_CUSTOM_MEMBER_FIELD}
```